# How to send a POST request to a REST API on a localhost with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, http-post

I'm trying to send a post request to a SREST API, which is currently on the localhost and keep getting various errors.

The error I'm getting at the moment is:

> requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The code I'm executing:

```
import requests 
import json 

def create_bucket():

    url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/buckets"

    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }

    params = {
        "bucket_name": "test_bucket"
    }

    response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)

    print(response.json())

create_bucket()
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Tried printing `response.content` as per request and got an error:

> `b'<!doctype html>\n<html lang=en>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>\n'`

**Edit 2:**

Solved the problem. Correct approach:

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
```

Comment: you aren't getting proper json, see what the API returns with `print(response.content)` instead of `print(reponse.json())`

Comment: Added the error to the post

Comment: Sorry, either try `json=params` or `params=json.dumps(params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the error, need to encode `json` properly, try:

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=params)
```

requests will do the [right thing](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

or

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, params=json.dumps(params))
```